# How to get Wget to retrieve entire url, including search terms

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wget

I'm trying to use a wget to retrieve a web page that that displays the results for a searched string. The page retrieved however, displays only the results of an empty string. From the looks of it, the search terms are placed in some sort of array. How do I use wget to retrieve the entire url?

`` name@ubuntu:~$ wget -U 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070802 SeaMonkey/1.1.4' http://www.somesite.com/search?tm_link=tm_header_search&user_input=search+of+terms&q=search+of+terms
[1] 2938
[2] 2939
name@ubuntu:~$ --2013-11-07 21:22:03--  http://www.somesite.com/search?tm_link=tm_header_search
Resolving www.somesite.com (www.somesite.com)... 23.42.84.199
Connecting to www.somesite.com (www.somesite.com)|23.42.84.199|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Syntax error in Set-Cookie: GEORAN=1; path=/; domain=.somesite.com; expires= at position 52.
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `search?tm_link=tm_header_search' ``

```
[ <=>                                   ] 146,249     --.-K/s   in 0.1s
```

2013-11-07 21:22:04 (1.14 MB/s) - `search?tm_link=tm_header_search' saved [146249]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shell invocation syntax is wrong. What you doing is calling `wget -U 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070802 SeaMonkey/1.1.4' http://www.somesite.com/search?tm_link=tm_header_search` (note `'` closed after user agent), and `&` is command to shell to set `wget` to background. Everything beyound this point is separate command.

You need to fix your command to something like `wget -U 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070802 SeaMonkey/1.1.4' 'http://www.somesite.com/search?tm_link=tm_header_search&user_input=search+of+terms&q=search+of+terms'`